# replacingOccurrences() for splitting a text into multiple lines via regular expression

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to use in a Search/Replace interface `String.replacingOccurrences(of:with:options:range:)` with the regular expression. This is the key point: let the user enter the patterns himself.

Any pattern of regular expression works fine in the Search field.

But I have a problem in the Replace field. My current program ignores the pattern "\n" for the new line. Instead of splitting the text into several lines it replaces multiple dots with the letter "n".

[What I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4W6k.png)

My code (Xcode 12, Swift 5):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var before: String = "1 Introduction....... 1 1.1 Communicating at a Distance................ 1 1.2 Computers Communicate Differently ................ 4 1.3 Early Wide Area Store-and-Forward Networks......... 5 1.4 Packets and Routers ...................... 6 1.5 Addressing and Packets.................... 7"
    
    @State private var searchString = ""
    @State private var replaceString = ""
    
    private var after: String {
        before.replacingOccurrences(
            of: searchString,
            with: replaceString,
            options: .regularExpression,
            range: .none
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Before")
                TextEditor(text: $before)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                
                Text("After")
                TextEditor(text: Binding.constant(after))
            }
            .padding()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text("Search")
                TextField("Empty", text: $searchString)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                
                Text("Replace")
                TextField("Empty", text: $replaceString)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 800, minHeight: 600, alignment: .top)
        .font(Font.system(size: 16))
    }
}
```

If I input into the Search field (into the field of the running program, not in the code) the text `\.+ \d+( )*` and into the Replace field the `\n` I expect to see this in the After field:

```
1 Introduction
1.1 Communicating at a Distance
1.2 Computers Communicate Differently 
1.3 Early Wide Area Store-and-Forward Networks
1.4 Packets and Routers 
1.5 Addressing and Packets
```

But in fact I see this:

```
1 Introductionn1.1 Communicating at a Distancen1.2 Computers Communicate Differently n1.3 Early Wide Area Store-and-Forward Networksn1.4 Packets and Routers n1.5 Addressing and Packetsn
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: The backslashes in the pattern must be escaped `"\\.+ \\d+( )*"`. For the replace string `\n` should do it without escaping backslashes.

Comment: @vadian Interesting. Your advice works really well if I hardcode the search/replace patterns. My initial problem occurs if the search/replace patterns are entered in the fields of running program. It looks like the distortion is due to the GUI. I updated my post with the full code of the program.

Comment: If the pattern is dynamic and depends on user input then the user is responsible for entering the correct pattern.

Answer (score 0):

to make your code work as you would like, ie type `\.+ \d+( )*` and `\n` , try this, works for me:

```
private var after: String {
    before.replacingOccurrences(
        of: searchString,
        with: replaceString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n"),
        options: .regularExpression,
        range: .none)
}
```

EDIT1:

Here is my test code that works for me when I type into the `TextFields`.
I'm using Xcode 13.1 on macos 12.1beta, targeting ios 15 and macCatalyst 12 and macos12 only. Tested
on real devices.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var before: String = "1 Introduction....... 1 1.1 Communicating at a Distance................ 1 1.2 Computers Communicate Differently ................ 4 1.3 Early Wide Area Store-and-Forward Networks......... 5 1.4 Packets and Routers ...................... 6 1.5 Addressing and Packets.................... 7"
    
    @State private var searchString = ""
    @State private var replaceString = ""
    
    private var after: String {
        before.replacingOccurrences(
            of: searchString,
            with: replaceString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n"),
            options: .regularExpression,
            range: .none)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Before")
                TextEditor(text: $before).padding(.bottom)
                Text("After")
                TextEditor(text: Binding.constant(after))
            }.padding()
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text("Search")
                TextField("Empty", text: $searchString).padding(.bottom)
                Text("Replace")
                TextField("Empty", text: $replaceString)
            }.padding()
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 800, minHeight: 600, alignment: .top)
        .font(Font.system(size: 16))
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's works if the patterns are written in the code. But I need arbitrary user input here, so I can't use string literals. This is the key point: let the user enter the patterns himself.

Comment: it works for me, when I type into the `TextFields`. I can type anything there and it works. Can you show an example that does not work for you.

Comment: updated my answer with the full code I use for my tests.